# Excel VBA Selenium Return URL required

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, oauth-2.0

I was using Internet Explorer to get an oauth code from an API.
Now that Internet Explorer has been discontinued, I am rewriting my code to work with selenium. However I have not been able to find a replacement for the i.e. `LocationURL`,
which returns the URL from the web browser. The Code I am after is returned through the URL of the browser. The old code fires up Internet Explorer to the Authentication URL, the user gets to type their credentials and the API returns the Authentication Token in the return URL.

The old Internet Explorer code is as follows:

```
Private Sub MYOB_Authentication()

    'This subroutine seeks the Access Token, Refresh Token and Expiry date of those
        
        Dim URL As String
        Dim Auth_Code As String
        Dim IE As InternetExplorer
        
       
    'This creates the necessary URL to navigate to (based upon the API Settings and according to the API Documentation)
        URL = "https://secure.myob.com/oauth2/account/authorize?client_id=" _
            & API_Key _
            & "&redirect_uri=" _
            & Application.WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(App_Url) _
            & "&response_type=code&scope=CompanyFile"
        
         Set IE = New InternetExplorer                                                              ' Create an instance of Internet Explorer
        With IE
            .Visible = True                                                                         ' Set the IE Window to visible
            .Navigate URL                                                                           ' Navigates to the URL created above
            URL = ""                                                                                ' Clear the URL value
            Application.Wait DateAdd("S", 2, Now())
            For Counter = 1 To 30                                                                   ' Generate loop to give the user time to login
                If .LocationURL Like "*code=*" Then                                                 ' Has the access code been received? (after the user has completed loging in)
                    Auth_Code = .LocationURL                                                        ' Set the Auth_Code variable to the current URL (redirected)
                    Exit For                                                                        ' User has completed login so exit out of loop
                End If
                Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now())                                             ' No code yet so wait 2 seconds before checking again
            Next Counter                                                                            ' Continue until 30 attempts have been made
            If Auth_Code = "" Then                                                                  ' Check if no Auth_Code variable (unsuccessful login)
                .Quit                                                                               ' Unsuccessful login so quit the IE application and close the window
                MsgBox "There was an error obtaining the Access Code", vbCritical, "No Access Code" ' Display error message to the user and exit
                Exit Sub                                                                            ' Can't continue without a successful login
            End If
            Auth_Code = Mid(Auth_Code, InStr(Auth_Code, "code=") + 5)                               ' Strips the Access Code out of the Auth_Code (the redirected URL)
            Auth_Code = UnEncodeURL(Auth_Code)                                                      ' Get the Access Code in plain string format (not URL Encoded)
            .Quit                                                                                   ' Quits the IE application (closes the window)
        End With
    ' Code continues
    
    I have downloaded and installed the Selenium drivers etc
    
    The new code i have so far is as follows:
    
    Private Sub MYOB_Authentication2()
    
    'This subroutine seeks the Access Token, Refresh Token and Expiry date of those
        
        Dim URL As String
        Dim Auth_Code As String
        Dim Edge As WebDriver
        
       
    'This creates the necessary URL to navigate to (based upon the API Settings and according to the API Documentation)
        URL = "https://secure.myob.com/oauth2/account/authorize?client_id=" _
            & API_Key _
            & "&redirect_uri=" _
            & Application.WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(App_Url) _
            & "&response_type=code&scope=CompanyFile"
        
        Set Edge = New WebDriver                                                                    ' Create an instance of Microsoft Edge
        Edge.Start "Edge", URL
        With Edge
            URL = ""                                                                                ' Clear the URL value
            Application.Wait DateAdd("S", 2, Now())
            For Counter = 1 To 30                                                                   ' Generate loop to give the user time to login
                If .URL Like "*code=*" Then                                                    ' Has the access code been received? (after the user has completed loging in)
                    Auth_Code = .LocationURL                                                        ' Set the Auth_Code variable to the current URL (redirected)
                    Exit For                                                                        ' User has completed login so exit out of loop
                End If
                Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now())                                             ' No code yet so wait 2 seconds before checking again
            Next Counter                                                                            ' Continue until 30 attempts have been made
            If Auth_Code = "" Then                                                                  ' Check if no Auth_Code variable (unsuccessful login)
                .Quit                                                                               ' Unsuccessful login so quit the IE application and close the window
                MsgBox "There was an error obtaining the Access Code", vbCritical, "No Access Code" ' Display error message to the user and exit
                Exit Sub                                                                            ' Can't continue without a successful login
            End If
            Auth_Code = Mid(Auth_Code, InStr(Auth_Code, "code=") + 5)                               ' Strips the Access Code out of the Auth_Code (the redirected URL)
            'Auth_Code = UnEncodeURL(Auth_Code)                                                      ' Get the Access Code in plain string format (not URL Encoded)
            .Quit                                                                                   ' Quits the IE application (closes the window)
        End With
```

The problem I get is that Edge does not navigate to the Authentication URL so user does not get to enter their credentials

I would be grateful for help in how to get this fixed and working.